# react-select comboBox accessibility. Screen reader not announcing the options provided

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I'm using `react-select` version `2.1.1`. I have created a combo box with 5 values. On focussing on combo box the screenReader reads out `ABC combo box` and on pressing `down` arrow key it announces `the expanded has popup`. Now when I try to press the down arrow key for selecting the options, the screenReader doesn't announce each option. Every option has been given `role=option`.

Comment: do you have a codepen or something to try the example?  what browser and screen reader were you using?

Comment: Using `Chrome Vox` screen reader. Tried in almost all the browsers. Also tried with `JAWS` in IE